# setSrc for IFRAME in Dynamics CRM unified form is not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-uci

I am following below walkthrough by J. Lattimar to add Documents navigation in CRM form tab. It was working fine in classical forms, but for unified forms the steps are not working and instead throw exception like An Error as has occurred. Any idea how to get this working?

https://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2017/01/show-sharepoint-documents-on-main-form.html

Comment: Did you verify my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Xrm.Page is deprecated, so you'll need to update this JS.  Start here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/get-started/whats-new/customer-engagement/important-changes-coming

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is unsupported approach we are following, author clearly called it out.

In UCI why it broke - [someone did investigation already](https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=0ea72a91-c959-4104-b77e-f937bc248f28&CommunityKey=dc83c23b-ede0-4070-ae7a-dd90859148a6&tab=digestviewer)

> Replacing `Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters().etc`
>   with "10069" ended up resolving this and currently works within UCI and Classic interfaces.

Actually couple of things to take care.

1. Like Hoffma said - `Xrm.Page` is deprecated, you have to rewrite the code to refer `formContext` from `executionContext`
2. `Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters()` is not containing the `etc` now, that's why breaking in UCI. You can supply the entity type code (etc) in the url manually